# Display only from a subsection of values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a set of vocabulary and currently, this is randomly displaying the image for one item from anywhere on the list (plus the clues in divs with ids b1, b2, b3). How can I make it display only entries that have "middle.Z" or "semantic.noun"?

```js
const quotes = [
    { 
    name: "Pizza",
    semantic: ["noun", "food"],
    initial: "P",
    middle: ["I", "Z"],
    final: "A",
    clues: ["...", "...", "..."],
    img: "/img/pizza.png",
  },
      { 
    name: "Bird",
    semantic: ["noun", "animal"],
    initial: "B",
    middle: ["I", "R"],
    final: "D",
    clues: ["...", "...", "..."],
    img: "/img/bird.png",
  }
  ]

const quote = quotes[Math.trunc(Math.random() * quotes.length)];

for (const [i, clue] of quote.clues.entries()) {
  document
    .getElementById(`b${i + 1}`)
    .appendChild(document.createElement("p")).textContent = clue;
}

document
  .getElementById("imgbox")
  .insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<center><img src="${quote.img}" alt="${quote.name}" /></center>`);
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
  <div id="imgbox" align= center>
      <div align=center> <button onClick="window.location.reload();">Refresh Page</button>
  </div>
   </div>
   <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="staticimage.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following?

```
quotes.filter(
  quote => quote.middle.some(m => m === 'Z') || // Object contains at least one 'Z' middle
  quote.semantic.some(s => s === 'noun') // Object contains at least one 'noun' semantic
)
```

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately, it did not work for me, I am not sure why.

Comment: What did it say when you ran it?

Comment: I do not have an error message; when I run it, it just doesn't filter out. It is still pulling randomly from the entire array for quotes.